# Image retrieve from folder with folder name in iOS

Tags: ios, path, uiimage

I have all my images in folder name ImageMe and I like to retrieve image with this name like

```
[UIImage imageNamed:@"ImageMe/bulk-female.jpg"];
```

how I get this approach, because I rereiving path name from data base, and in that format it's coming.

Comment: where is store this images in you document directory or your resource bundle.?

Comment: just use [UIImage imageNamed:@"bulk-female.jpg"];

Comment: check out my answer helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to modify these images, just create folder name "Resource" under supporting files and save ImageMe folder with your images there. Then use below code to get path of image folder.

```
NSString *theResourcePath = [NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
NSString *theFilePath = [theResourcePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ImageMe/bulk-female.jpg"];
```

Comment: itry as suggested, create the Resource folder, than insede it create folder and save images, and use ur cod to get  image to display, but not coming

Comment: Check whether you are getting resource folder path or not?One more thing I am posting from windows machines so may not know exact method, so google how to get path of resource folder, append your folder path and get your image.To get image you can use:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourimagename.png"];

Answer (score 0):

If you have the images in the main bundle you can get them with
`[UIImage imageNamed:@"theNameOfTheImage_WithOutDirecotry"];`.

You have to specify only the image name not the directory. This is because when the application is packed in .ipa only the images are copied (the images that are in the Copy Bundle Resources) not the directories.

If you want to pack the images in to one folder you have to create a new bundle but you can not use `imageNamed` you have to use `initWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)path`

Here are some docs [UIImage](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html), [NSBundle](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html), [Bundle Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/AboutBundles/AboutBundles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i-CH100-SW1)

Answer (score 0):

If your all images are present in bundle then you can directly get that images from name.

like this

```
[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.jpg"];

[UIImage imageNamed:@"2.jpg"]

[UIImage imageNamed:@"3.jpg"]
```

directly get the images using their names.

And if you want to laod that images to particular folder of bundle.

```
NSString *Path = [NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
NSString *FilePath = [Path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ImageMe/bulk-female.jpg"];
```

try this one this might be helpful to you.

Comment: [NSBundle mainBundle] Path], what is Path in this

Comment: user2256034 sory it's my mistake it is resource path where you want to save the image in bundle.

Answer (score 0):

Add your images in a floder & than add that folder to your project like this

[image: As shown in image, please select the option, Create folder references for any added folder]

after adding the folder to your project, you can access your images with the following code.

```
NSString *bundlePath = [NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSString *imagePath = [bundlePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ImageFolder/imagename.jpg"];
```

Hope this will solve your problem